# Smoke Simulation Appears in Solid View, But Not in Renders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I can't get my smoke simulation to appear in renders. It does appear in the viewport in solid view. Why won't this smoke simulation appear in the renders?

This is the render on frame 766:
[image]

This is the solid view images displaying the settings of the smoke domain physics properties tab:
[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the solid view images displaying the settings of the smoke emitter physics properties tab:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a material for the fluid domain?

Comment: As @BlenderUser123 suspects, I would also say there is no material on the smoke domain.

Comment: Yes you are both correct this fixed it! I simply needed to add a material to the smoke domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually extremely easy to fix, you just need to add a material to the smoke domain. Just go to the materials tab with the smoke domain selected and apply a material.